# Why does VBA insert five row instead of one

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to insert row in sheet but instead of inserting only 1 row, I insert 5. Thanks for any help.
FinalRngA and FinalRngB are rows in sheet, that i declared before with for loop.

````
        If Sheets(shtName).Range(FinalRngB(i)) <> Sheets(shtName).Range(FinalRngB(i - 1)) And i > 1 Then
            Sheets(shtName).Range(FinalRngA(i)).EntireRow.Insert
            Sheets(shtName).Range(FinalRngA(i)) = Sheets(shtName).Range(FinalRngB(i + 2))
        End If
    Next```
````

Comment: Because `Sheets(shtName).Range(FinalRngB(i)) <> Sheets(shtName).Range(FinalRngB(i - 1)) And i > 1` is `True` 5 times?

Comment: what? no, why would it?

Comment: Also possible if `Sheets(shtName).Range(FinalRngA(i))` has 5 rows, then doing `.EntireRow.Insert` would insert 5 rows. If you want just one row, do `.Rows(1).EntireRow.Insert`

Comment: sorry, here si the whole loop
```For i = 1 To xRows
        If Sheets(shtName).Range(FinalRngB(i)) <> Sheets(shtName).Range(FinalRngB(i - 1)) And i > 1 Then
            Sheets(shtName).Range(FinalRngA(i)).Insert
            Sheets(shtName).Range(FinalRngA(i)) = Sheets(shtName).Range(FinalRngB(i + 2))
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Please create a [reprex] - we have no idea what `FinalRngB` does for example.

Comment: You could add a `Debug.Print i` inside the `If` to see on what iterations row(s) are being inserted

Comment: the FinalRngB is B column where i copy data from another sheet

Answer (score 2):

`Range.Insert` will insert a range the same size and shape as itself.

### Demo

[image: Range Insert]

---

### Test Code

```
Sub TestInsert(RowCount As Long, ColumnCount As Long)
    Cells.ClearContents
    Range("A1").Resize(100, 100).Value = "x"
    Range("A1").Resize(RowCount, ColumnCount).Insert
    Range("A1").Resize(RowCount, ColumnCount).Select
    Range("A1").Resize(RowCount, ColumnCount).Value = RowCount & "x" & ColumnCount
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly, So if you only want one row to be inserted, you should ensure the target Range is a single row `Range(...).Rows(1).EntireRow.Insert`